# scala.tools.nsc.Global fails to compile after first compilation error

Tags: scala, compilation, twirl

I've implemented dynamic compilation of Twirl templates and stumbled upon odd problem - instance of `scala.tools.nsc.Global` works until it fails once with bad source file. Any further attempts to compile valid file fail, it does not produce `.class` binaries. I'm on Scala 2.11.8.

How can I debug and fix this?

Here is how I create instance of `Global`:

```
private def createScalaCompiler(compileErrors: mutable.ListBuffer[CompilationError]): Global = {

  val additionalClassPathEntry: String =
    List(twirlCompilerClass, this.getClass).flatMap(_.getClassLoader.asInstanceOf[URLClassLoader].getURLs.map(_.getFile)).distinct.mkString(":")

  val settings = new Settings()
  settings.debug.tryToSet(Nil)
  settings.verbose.tryToSet(Nil)

  val scalaObjectSource = Class.forName("scala.Int").getProtectionDomain.getCodeSource
  if (scalaObjectSource != null) {
    val compilerPath = Class.forName("scala.tools.nsc.Interpreter").getProtectionDomain.getCodeSource.getLocation
    val libPath = scalaObjectSource.getLocation
    val pathList = List(compilerPath, libPath)
    val origBootclasspath = settings.bootclasspath.value
    settings.bootclasspath.value = ((origBootclasspath :: pathList) ::: Some(additionalClassPathEntry).toList) mkString File.pathSeparator
    settings.outdir.value = generatedClasses.getAbsolutePath
  }

  val compiler: Global = new Global(settings, new ConsoleReporter(settings) {
    override def printMessage(pos: Position, msg: String): Unit = {
      pos match {
        case NoPosition =>
          println(msg)
        case _ =>
          compileErrors.append(CompilationError(msg, pos.line, pos.point))
      }
    }
  })

  compiler
}
```

which I use as follows

```
val compileErrors = new mutable.ListBuffer[CompilationError]
val compiler = createScalaCompiler(compileErrors)
```

then instance of `compiler` is used multiple times in function similar to

```
def compileScalaFile(fakePath: String, content: String) {
  val run = new compiler.Run
  val sourceFile = new BatchSourceFile(new VirtualFile(fakePath), content)
  run.compileSources(List(sourceFile))
}
```

As you see I enabled verbose logging. Interestingly compilation of valid scala code doesn't produce any output to log,

It seems to me that `compiler` goes into broken state. How do I reset it without recreating it from scratch (which takes time in production) ?